# In Andriod, using tess-two OCR, is it possible to enable opencl?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, opencl, tesseract, tess-two

I'm currently working on a self-proposed project. It involves tess-two, an Android friendly version of the tesseract OCR engine.

As of now the application works, but I want to add in GPU usage capabilities. I've been able to compile tesseract on Ubuntu 16.04 with OpenCL enabled, and was wondering if I could do the same on the Android platform.

Things to note:

- Not all phones have the OpenCL library built-in. However, a good
  portion of them do.
- I've taken a look at the Android.mk to see if
  there's anything to be tweaked there, but again, totally lost. 
  https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two/blob/master/tess-two/jni/com_googlecode_tesseract_android/Android.mk
- This whole "enable OpenCL and GPU" part is somewhat optional. I
  really just want to know how to do it.
- EDIT: Is it enabled to begin with? :'D

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44897271/295004 also search on OpenCV along with appropriate keywords to see what others have done.